# Recoding a variable with R

Tags: r

My dataset "d" has the variable Hist containing 1 - 9 and a weird "#I/T"-value. I think "#I/T" has been imported from Excel.

However, I want to rewrite d$Hist so it only keeps values between 1 - 9. I cant figure it out though. I tried:

d$Hist <- d$Hist[1:9]

or

d <- subset(data=d, d$Hist[1:9])

Hope you can help me :)

Regards,
C.

Comment: Could that be someone's idea of coding a missing value?

Comment: The value is missing, yes. I tried using d <- d[!is.na(d)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are two differenty ways of doing what you want. I believe I prefer the second, I find it safer. This is because when it comes to objects of class `factor` you will never know.
First, make up some data.

```
set.seed(9486)    # make it reproducible
d <- data.frame(Hist = sample(c("#I/T", 1:9), 20, TRUE), X = rnorm(20))
d$Hist

d2 <- subset(d, Hist %in% 1:9)
d3 <- subset(d, as.character(Hist) %in% as.character(1:9))
identical(d2, d3)
#[1] TRUE
```

As you can see the results are the same.
**Note:** in your code you have `subset(data=d, d$Hist ...)`. When you use `subset` you don't need to repeat the name of the data frame, `d$Hist`, just `Hist` would do it.

Comment: Thank you! Im obviously a beginner in R. d2 <- subset(d, Hist %in% 1:9) did the thing!

Comment: Hi again. I posted an answer to my question further down the page - can you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this

```
d$Hist <- as.numeric( gsub("[^1-9]*","",d$Hist) )
```

For example

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^1-9]*","","$#I/T7"))
```

returns number 7.

Answer (score 0):

So i did this (which removed "#I/T" from "d" to "d2")

```
d2 <- subset(d, Hist %in% 1:9)
```

However, I ran my analysis (relative survival) like this:

```
model.hist <- rstrans(Surv(time, cens)~as.factor(d2$Hist)+ratetable(year = year, 
age = age, sex = sex), ratetable = poptab)

summary(model.hist)
```

And the analysis showed this:

```
                          coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
as.factor(d2$Hist)          NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
as.factor(d2$Hist)#I/T      NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
as.factor(d2$Hist)10        NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
as.factor(d2$Hist)2    0.32796   1.38814  0.06651  4.931 8.19e-07 ***
as.factor(d2$Hist)3    1.66204   5.27007  0.31904  5.210 1.89e-07 ***
as.factor(d2$Hist)4    2.29242   9.89889  0.06819 33.618  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(d2$Hist)5    0.72273   2.06004  0.08140  8.878  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(d2$Hist)6    1.56012   4.75939  0.16974  9.191  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(d2$Hist)8    0.12813   1.13670  0.11248  1.139    0.255    
as.factor(d2$Hist)9    1.36726   3.92458  0.10316 13.254  < 2e-16 ***
```

Cant figure out why

- "#I/T" still is in the analysis
- What (d2$Hist)10 is, as i only have Hist 1-9

Comment: OK, you need `?droplevels` to get rid of the level `#I/T`. And 10 is probably how `#I/T` was coded. `R` codes factors as integers and you have `1:9` plus that ugly thing. `d2$Hist <- droplevels(d2$Hist)` will take care of it. See the help page.